# How to translate new-added text?

Tags: 7, emails, i18n-l10n

I use Contact and Locale modules. I wanted to change text included in e-mail so I went to modules/contact/contact.module and I replaced appropriate lines. Unfortunately, that text is not translate to my national language (of course is understanding). How can I add translation to new-added text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [never change code in Drupal core](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core), change back to the original code in contact.module first.

When you have the Locale module enabled and have added your language (Configuration -> Regional and language -> Languages) you can translate strings. You will find the translate interface under Configuration -> Regional and language -> Translate interface.

Search for the English phrase first to find the string you want to translate (use exact spelling, it's case sensitive) and add your translation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I wanted. But what should I do if I'd like to remove some text from e-mail. Should I replace text in English with empty string?

Comment: You could add an empty translation to the English text. Then people using your national language will get an empty string. Would that work?

Comment: I suppose that after adding an empty translation to the English text that text will not be translated. Perhaps I may translate text as single space, yet in my estimation is unattractive.